# How to load the unity content on button click in a web page?

Tags: html, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I have created a unity webGL project, here i am looking for a way like once the progress bar is full,a button will appear on the web page.
On clicking the button unity content should load.
Is this possible?

Comment: Sounds more like a JavaScript related question and barely touching Unity ...

Comment: Checkout the [templates](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-templates.html) .. I'm no WebGL nor JavaScript expert but as I see it all you need to do is wait with the `var unityInstance = UnityLoader.instantiate("unityContainer", "%UNITY_WEBGL_BUILD_URL%");` call until your button is pressed? Further at the bottom there is even a section `Adding a progress bar` which is probably what you are looking for?

Comment: I have tried it,But once the progress bar is full the unity content  is running in background.How to control loading of the unity content on button click?